# unable to compile quarto document using kableextra and table caption

Tags: xetex, r, quarto

I have been trying out `Quarto` as a replacement for `RMarkdown` for writing reports but come across some problems with tables.

The main issue seems to be that I cannot get it to compile if I am trying to use both a table caption, and also some of the nice tools available in `kableExtra` to create nice looking `LaTeX` tables, see code below:

````
---
title: "REPREX - QMD KABLE CAPTION COMPILATION PROBLEM"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: article
    code-line-numbers: true
latex-output-dir: ../output
keep-tex: true
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| include: false
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

tbl <- tribble(
  ~"pos_neg",  ~"<8", ~"8-10", ~">10",
  "Negative", 95, 23, 45,
  "Positive", 49, 22, 25,
  )
```

```{r}
#| tbl-cap: Test
#| label: tbl-test

tbl %>% 
  janitor::adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col")) %>%
  kable(
    longtable = TRUE,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    linesep = "",
    align = c("l", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
    col.names = c("", names(.)[-1]),
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Inoculum volume (mL)" = 3, " " = 1), bold = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(0, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(2:4, width = "3em")
```
````

I get this error returned:

> compilation failed- error Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token
> (\caption): `c' used.
>
> See the array package documentation for explanation. Type  H 
> for immediate help.  ...
> l.238 ...{3em}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}c}

This is the tex code outputted for the table:

```
\begin{longtable}{>{}
\caption{\label{tbl-test}Test }\tabularnewline
l>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ }} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Inoculum volume (mL)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ }} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-4}
\textbf{} & \textbf{<8} & \textbf{8-10} & \textbf{>10} & \textbf{Total}\\
\midrule
\textbf{Negative} & 95 & 23 & 45 & 163\\
\textbf{Positive} & 49 & 22 & 25 & 96\\
\textbf{Total} & 144 & 45 & 70 & 259\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

If I remove the `#| tbl-cap: Test` chunk option it compiles but obviously without the table caption.

If anyone is able to help I would be grateful.

Thanks

> [✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
> Version: 1.2.475
> Path: /Applications/quarto/bin
>
> [✓] Checking basic markdown render....OK
>
> [✓] Checking R installation...........OK
> Version: 4.2.2
> Path: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R
> LibPaths:
> - /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library
> rmarkdown: 2.21
>
> [✓] Checking Knitr engine render......OK
>
> Darwin mac-mini.lan 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6
> 21:00:17 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
>
> tlmgr revision 66798 (2023-04-08 02:15:21 +0200) tlmgr
> using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2023 TeX Live
> (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2023
>
> TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) kpathsea version 6.3.5
>
> knitr_1.42
> rmarkdown_2.21
> janitor_2.2.0
> kableExtra_1.3.4
> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: the latex code is wrong. As it is produced if the kableExtra is used report it there.

Comment: Are you sure this is not happening because table caption is not quoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a answer, but I cannot explain well in a comment:

Your problem is not reproducible for some reason. Something outdated? You are making something not showed? (always show a mininal working example compilable "as is", not snippets that have, for instance, one  R chunk without the end marks).

Reconstructing you file, or something similar (?) the header of the table with caption is correct in my computer:

```
\begin{longtable}{>{}l>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}c}
\caption{\label{tbl-test}Test }\tabularnewline

\toprule
...
```

An the table is rendered correctly:

[image: mwe]

The whole Quarto used for this output:

````
---
title: "REPREX - QMD KABLE CAPTION COMPILATION PROBLEM"
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: article
    code-line-numbers: true
latex-output-dir: ../output
keep-tex: true
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| include: false
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

tbl <- tribble(
  ~"pos_neg",  ~"<8", ~"8-10", ~">10",
  "Negative", 95, 23, 45,
  "Positive", 49, 22, 25,
  )
```

```{r}
#| tbl-cap: Test
#| label: tbl-test

tbl %>% 
  janitor::adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col")) %>%
  kable(
    longtable = TRUE,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    linesep = "",
    align = c("l", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
    col.names = c("", names(.)[-1]),
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Inoculum volume (mL)" = 3, " " = 1), bold = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(0, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(2:4, width = "3em")
```
````

Comment: thanks I have rewrittent the question to try to make it easier to follow and added the versions of the relevant packages used. Are you running the same package versions?

Comment: At least  quarto and R are newer in my PC (1.3.324 y R 4.2.3)

Comment: thanks. I have just upgraded quarto to 1.3.333 (latest available for MacOS at this time) and the issue seems to have resolved itself.